# Missing Settings on Light Point Menu

Tags: rendering, light, properties, shadows

I am new to blender, trying to edit light and shadow parameters. I came across the following.

I had added a light point to the workspace. When I click on it (the light point object), the menu on the right-hand sidebar does not display the Light settings that I would expect.

The available settings are *Transform, relations, collections, instancing, motion paths, visibility, viewport display, and custom properties*.

I have looked for any light or shadow properties settings but I cannot find them.

Comment: Hi and welcome :) What are the settings your expecting to see? Would you mind [editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/197271/edit) your question and adding an image or two to clarify please what you are trying to do? This will help others help you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found them, they were just on a separate tab (withing the right-hand bar menu) instead. Which holds these properties.